# jQuery: Getting the active link index returns always 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple menu with 3 links, on click on one of the links I am setting the active class to that specific link. What I am trying to achieve is to see which element was clicked and which one had the active class so I can make an animation in jQuery.

My operator will always give me `-=` because activeIndex is always 0 and the clickIndex are actually correct.

What can be a solution to make this work?

```js
$('.tabs').on('click', 'li > a', function() {
  let tabs = $('.tabs');
  let activeIndex = $('a.active', tabs).index();
  let clickedIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();

  let operator = (activeIndex > clickedIndex) ? '+=' : '-=';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="another-class active">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="another-class">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="another-class">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `active` class is applied to the first link, which is at index 0. Why would it be anything else?

Comment: Sorry i do not understand, you are trying to animate currently clicked item?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve here @NinetyHH ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just put a small example to show that I have a simple menu, what I was meaning is that the active class is added on click through another function.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I am trying to get the correct operator, so for example if active right now is in the second link which should be index 1, i want to see if the user clicked link 2 or link 0. So i can animate({ left: operator + 50px });

Comment: Could you please be more precise around the goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well you are reading the index of the active link inside of the li, not reading the li's index.

Comment: I do not add the active class to the list elements, i do on the a elements. Shouldn't be the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
$('.tabs').on('click', 'li > a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $active = $('.tabs').find("li.active");
  let activeIndex = $active.index();
  let $clicked = $(this).closest('li');
  let clickedIndex = $clicked.index();
  $active.removeClass("active");
  $clicked.addClass("active");
  let operator = (activeIndex > clickedIndex) ? '+=' : '-=';
  console.log(activeIndex,clickedIndex,operator)
});
```

```css
.active { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" class="another-class">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="another-class">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="another-class">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats really close from what I needed, my first tries was actually setting <a> class to active and not lists, i just modified a bit the code and worked.